# Using synchronous encryption on RSA keys

Tags: java, encryption, random, cryptography, public-key-encryption

Would it make sense to encrypt the RSA keys of an encryption program I am writing with the java random number generator and a password as a seed? How secure would that make them?

Comment: If you are **seriously** interested in security, then there are no shortcuts. Then you have to bite the bullet and study this topic in depth. Get the book from Bruce Schneier and start reading. Coming up with "good" ideas and using "stack overflow" to "validate" their correctness is unprofessional; and when you are really working on a real product ... utterly ridiculous.

Comment: 'Synchronous' encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may make your RSA keys safer than you could expect. If the random number generator ever changes or if the password is only added as a seed then you lose the encrypted data.

You can always encrypt private keys with a password, but you should be using a known password based key derivation function (PBKDF) such as PBKDF2. PBKDF2 is specified in [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898): PKCS #5: Password-Based Cryptography Specification v2.0.

So yes, encrypting a private key can provide a layer of protection. It should however not be performed with a random number generator. A well known protocol that encrypts the private key using a password is PGP. Password encryption can also be performed for the PKCS#12 container format (which actually refers back to PKCS#5).

How security it is depends on the system. A weak password will certainly hurt security though.